# Selecting and comparing the averages of multiple SQL tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm doing a NBA database with random data refering a team (for example the Lakers). The thing here is that I have a table for each season and in each season-table I have the game number, the player name, points, assists, rebounds, steals and blocks. What i want to do and don't know how to express it in an SQL sentence or multiple is to ask: select the avg of points, avg assists, avg rebounds... of ONE season of ONE player that for example averaged more than 25 points, 5 assists and 5 rebounds, in a SINGLE season. So that a player did it multiple times in multiple seasons, it appears the averages of that player multiple times.

Comment: Is this MySQL or Postgres?  You have both tags.  Post what SQL you have, some sample data and expected output.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Written in postgres, the CTE is a UNION of all your different tables, with calculated averages using each respective table. Then you simply select from the CTE.

```
with seasons as (
 select '2018' as season, player, 
   avg(points) as avg_points, 
   avg(assists) as avt_assists, 
   avg(rebounds) as avg_rebounds, 
   avg(steals) as avg_steals,
   avg(blocks) as avg_blocks
  from table1
 group by 1, 2
 union  
 select '2019' as season, player, 
   avg(points) as avg_points, 
   avg(assists) as avt_assists, 
   avg(rebounds) as avg_rebounds, 
   avg(steals) as avg_steals,
   avg(blocks) as avg_blocks
  from table2
 group by 1, 2
 union
 select '2020' as season, player, 
   avg(points) as avg_points, 
   avg(assists) as avt_assists, 
   avg(rebounds) as avg_rebounds, 
   avg(steals) as avg_steals,
   avg(blocks) as avg_blocks
  from table3
 group by 1, 2
)
select *
  from seasons
 where avg_points > 25
   and avg_assists > 5
   and avg_rebounds > 5
```